# Comparing current date and future date

Tags: javascript

**Situation**  I have a dynamic table sourced from an Oracle DB. There is a column called "ScheduledTime" which is a TIMEStamp/shortTime, and that variable is compared to a client-side javascript digital clock. If the scheduledTime variable is within a particular time of the current time (js clock) then we return action on the table row.

i.e  if "scheduledTime" is <=15mins of currentTime then color row red

**The issue**
When its 23:00(11pm) and there is an item scheduled for 2am(next day), the logic thinks the item is late because its reading "2" furthermore making the table row color red.

**Question/Possible solution**
I'm thinking I should run a condition before the color coding that would compare the TimeStamp dates rather than time. If the dates are not equal then dont execute the color logic... What are your thoughts..

Current code

```
 var t = new Date();

 for (var i = 1, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
        var hm = row.cells[0].innerText.split(":");
        t.setHours(hm[0], hm[1], 0, 0);
        var r = (t.getTime() - current.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60;


        if(r <= 0.25)
            row.className = "Red";
        else if (r > 0.25 & r <= 0.5)
            row.className = "Yellow";
        else if (r > 0.5 & r <= 2)
            row.className = "Green";
```

Comment: If you have dates on different days, setting only hours and minutes of `t` obviously won't be enough. Parse the *whole* date. Have you tried your "possible solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library will help you parse the date text from the table into a real JS Date() object that you can use for further comparisons/manipulation:

https://code.google.com/p/datejs/#Parsing

Answer (score 0):

On a few projects where I needed to do time range calculations I used moment-range JavaScript library: https://github.com/gf3/moment-range

It should be able to handle what you need. you'll need to use full date and time, however.